# Canvas Video and CORS Issue in IE and Safari

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, canvas, cors

I have a canvas element that uses `getImageData()` and `putImageData()` onto a canvas. My `<video>` element has a property of `crossorigin="anonymous"`.

The video is coming from S3/Cloudfront. My bucket has this CORS config right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

This works great in Chrome and Firefox. I am successfully drawing video onto the canvas.

My issue is with Safari and IE (11 specifically, but from what I understand it's an IE10+ issue).

When I attempt this in IE or Safari, I get this error:

`Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`

I understand the error because before I setup CORS, chrome and firefox was giving the same error. Adding CORS fixed it for chrome and firefox but not IE and Safari.

I noticed the response headers of the video were different from say chrome to IE.